# Update column from one DB table to another

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have DatabaseA which has table Episodes

I have restored a backup of that database locally (lets call that DatabaseB) a while back to my localhost instance in SQL Server.

I f'd up Episodes.Description in DatabaseA and want to restore that by selecting Description from the one on my local instance and to match by Episodes.ID

Not sure hot to go about that and also how to reference the different server instances (DatabaseB (local vs. the server housing DatabaseA

here's the updated statement that messed up all files, I forgot to highlight the where clause, classic stupid mistake and so it updated everything with the same description:

```
  update episode set description = 
    'some text here'
```

[image]

so I wanna do something like this assuming I have context to the live server while in management studio which is why I'm not fully qualifying the server for the first part, only for local I am (non-working pseudo cod here):

```
update episode set [description] = [description] from [CHICAGOLAPTOP\MSSQLSERVER].[DimeCastsDotNet].[dbo].[Episode] episodeLocal
where ID = episodeLocal.ID
```

Comment: I think you can either create a linked server or use SSIS. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx

Comment: would rather not fire up SSIS, I just want a quick sql script to do this

Comment: Then you need to create a linked server

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a linked server on either side and then you access it by the 4 part name.

[Linked Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)

Little more efficient if you create the link at the server that is being updated.